# Recreate file in same relative location across devices

Tags: android, filesystems, device

I want to send the path of a file found on one Android device to some other Android device and recreate the file in the same relative place as it was on the previous device.

There are no guarantees made about make, model, API level or anything of the like.

Can I do this?

Essentially I'm wondering if I can use some type of File.get*Path() without doing anything super fancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, there is no way to accomplish this as simply as calling a get*Path() function found in File.java but here's a general algorithm of what can be done.

General algorithm:

1. Determine which known root the file exists under on device A.
2. Send the known root name and the canonical path to the file to device B
3. On device B, create the file with the path relative to the known root.

   ```
   //assume these constants are accessible on device A and B
   public static String FILES_DIR = "f";
   public static String EXTERNAL_FILES_DIR = "e";

   //Device A:
   File f = new File(getFilesDir(), "test.txt");
   String canonicalPath = f.getCanonicalPath();
   Packet p = new Packe(FILES_DIR, canonicalPath);
   sendPacket(p, DEVICE_B);

   //Device B:
   Packet p = receivePacket();
   String token = p.getToken();
   String canonicalPath = p.getCanonicalPath();
   if (token.equals(FILES_DIR)) {
       File f = new File(getFilesDir(), relativizeToRoot(FILES_DIR, canonicalPath));
       writeFile(f);
   } else if (token.equals(EXTERNAL_DIR)) {
       File f = new File(getExternalFilesDir(), relativizeToRoot(EXTERNAL_FILES_DIR, canonicalPath));
   }
   ```

This is generally how Google does it when backing up files that might be recreated on devices with different file structures as referenced here http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/backup/BackupAgent.java#315